# How to customize error message sent to an end-user when bot's endpoint is unavailable?

Tags: botframework

If a user sends message to a bot while it's endpoint is unavailable or failed processing the message, the user receives an error message from Bot Connector, which seems like that:

> POST to **{SomeArbitraryBot}** failed: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 502

or

> POST to **{SomeArbitraryBot}** failed: A task was canceled.

etc.

Is there a way to customize logic of sending error message or to suppress it at all in such a case?

**UPDATE**

I posted a [corresponding issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1754) at [Bot Builder GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder).

Comment: Up to now, it's an open issue in bot framework and will be developed in the future.